# 2's complement minimum bits of a given number

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, computer-science, cpu-architecture, twos-complement

I'm trying to figure it out but still stuck.

Let's say we have the decimal number **13 (1101 in binary)**. At unsigned, we need minimum 4 bits to represent it (1101 as it is) but in 2's complement signed do we need 5 bits with the MSbit set to 0 because 13 is a positive number? I know that in 2's complement, the MSbit indicates the sign of the value (+ or -). So it will be 01101?
Also, if the MSbit is 0, the number is still the same in singed 2's complement but if it is 1 then is will be As = Au - 2^n.

Let's say now that the number is **-13**. To find out the binary form of -13, i flip all the bits of 13 (1's complement) and then add +1 to them (2's complement). So in this case we have: `1101 ---> 0010 + 1 ---> 0011` but in singed 2's complement the MSbit is 0 (so it's positive) and we say "**this is the number 3**" or can we 1 as the new MSbit to look like negative (like 11101)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In two's-complement, positive numbers have an infinite number of leading zeroes, and negative numbers have an infinite number of leading ones.  To allow storage in a finite space, the leftmost digit of a representation will be repeated infinitely far to the left.  Since the number 13 needs to lead off with an infinite number of zeroes, its representation must start with a zero.  The shortest representation would thus be 01101, but other representations with arbitrary numbers of zeroes (like 00001101 or 0000000000001101) would be just as valid.

Although it's possible to negate a number by flipping all the bits and adding 1, I think it's more helpful to simply subtract from zero.  If one subtracts ...01101 from ...00000, the last digit will be 1 with a borrow, then 1 with a borrow, 0 with a borrow, 0 with a borrow, and 1 with a borrow.  Since all remaining digits in both the value being subtracted (...01101) and the value being subtracted from (...00000) will be zeroes, every remaining digit in the result will be a 1 with a borrow.

Comment: Yeah i got what you are saying. Mind to take a look at the new updated question? (another example shown up).

Comment: @DarkSysOp: Added some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say now that the number is -13. To find out the binary form of -13, i flip all the bits of 13 (1's complement) and then add +1 to them (2's complement). So in this case we have: 1101 ---> 0010 + 1 ---> 0011

You didn't flip all the bits, because negating a number implies using **signed** representations. You give the bits representing 13 as `1101b`, which is **not** signed. If it were signed, it would represent another number, namely `101b` + 1 = `110b` = 6, hence -6.

You must ensure, that a positive number, such as 13, does indeed have a 0 as its MSB, exactly as you have shown to be in its minimal form: `01101b`. Swapping these you obtain `10010b`, adding 1 then yields `10011b`, which in your 5-bit-bytes does indeed represent -13.

Using the more common 8-bit byte, you would find `11110011` for the negative value and `00001101` for the positive. (Note, that flipping all bits and adding 1 is used in both directions.)